Comment Image Upload - upload images directly from the comment box!




Screenshots



About
Comment Image Upload script allows one to upload images directly from the comment box: by dragging and dropping them, pasting them from other sources, or selecting them from the computer.
License
The script is licensed under the GPL-3.0-or-later license.
Download
Latest version: 0.2.2
Install | Minified
Contact
Author: 0valt
Contributor: double-beep
Organization: UserScripters
Please, submit bug reports on the source repository.
Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.
You can also drop by to chat, we are a friendly bunch.
Code
Source code is written in TypeScript.
Contributions are welcome, you can always submit a PR here.
